# Use conditional between two separate dict values in Ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible, conditional-statements

```
alpha:
  - type: a
    quantity: 1
  - type: b
    quantity: 2
  - type: c
    quantity: 3
---
bravo:
  - type: a
    quantity: 1
  - type: b
    quantity: 2
  - type: c
    quantity: 1
```

I have two lists of dictionaries. What I want to do is only return the type and quantity from alpha if they quantity is lower than the corresponding value in bravo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        delta: "{{ delta|default([]) + [item.0] }}"
      loop: "{{ alpha|sort(attribute='type')|
                zip(bravo|sort(attribute='type'))|
                list }}"
      when: item.0.quantity < item.1.quantity
    - debug:
        var: delta
```

In the data, no alpha quality is lower compared to the corresponding bravo. The variable delta will be undefined.